# Pass SharedPreferences value to another method in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I want to get SharedPreferences value in initState of the page and pass the value to another method which returns Future too. But just because the SharedPreferences returns a Future which is its normal result, i can't pass it's value to another method. It always returns "null", here is my SharedPref method:

```
Future<String> getTenantId() async {
    SharedPreferences appPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final tenantId = appPreferences.getString("tenantId");

    if(tenantId == null) {
      return null;
    }

    return tenantId;
  }
```

And in my initState method:

```
@override

      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
        
        final tenantId = getTenantId();
        tenantId.then((value) => {
          _debitInvoiceFuture = dInvoiceRep.getSingleDebitInvoiceById(widget.dId, value)
        });
        
      }
```

"dInvoiceRep.getSingleDebitInvoiceById(widget.dId, value)" this line returns Future and i use it with FutureBuilder widget to build the UI. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write one method that returns the `Future` you need:

```
void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    
    _debitInvoiceFuture = _getDebitInvoiceFuture(); 
}

Future<?> _getDebitInvoiceFuture() async { // figure out what future your getSingleDebitInvoiceById returns
  final appPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final tenantId = await appPreferences.getString("tenantId");
  return dInvoiceRep.getSingleDebitInvoiceById(widget.dId, tenantId)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
@override

      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
        
        Future<String> tenantId = Future(getTenantId());
        tenantId.then((value) => {
          _debitInvoiceFuture = Future (dInvoiceRep.getSingleDebitInvoiceById(widget.dId, value));
        });
        
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

When I try to use a future in the `initState` I use Future

```
Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
  _debitInvoiceFuture = await dInvoiceRep.getSingleDebitInvoiceById(widget.dId, value)
});
```